# Clico no botão e não adiciona a div - C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, click

Clico no botão e ele não me adiciona a div, mas manda para a base de dados, alguém pode me ajudar?

**C#**

```
protected void img_btn_enviar_nome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UtilizadoresBot msg_nome = new UtilizadoresBot
            {

                Nome = txt_msg_nome.Text,

            };
            db.UtilizadoresBot.InsertOnSubmit(msg_nome);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            div_conversa.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p class='p_cliente'> 1 " + msg_nome + "</p>"));
            div_conversa.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='clear: both'></div>"));

        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_conversa" class="div_conversa" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O atributo `runat="server"` só deve ser utilizado para os componentes do ASP.Net, aqueles em que o markup começa com `<asp:` ou alguma outra tagprefix que você tenha registrado em sua página. Nesse caso o mais adequado seria utilizar um `<asp:panel>` que seria renderizado como uma `<div>`.

E nesse seu cenário não parece ser necessário ter esse componente sendo rederizado no lado do servidor. Outra coisa que não faz sentido é você adicionar controles `Literal` apenas para incluir um HTML cru na página... Você poderia utilizar uma `<div>` simples e aí sim, dentro dela utilizar um `<asp:Literal>` para receber o novo conteúdo.

**ASPX**

```
<div id="div_conversa" class="div_conversa">
    <asp:Literal ID="conversa" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void img_btn_enviar_nome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UtilizadoresBot msg_nome = new UtilizadoresBot
    {

        Nome = txt_msg_nome.Text,

    };
    db.UtilizadoresBot.InsertOnSubmit(msg_nome);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    conversa.Text += "<p class='p_cliente'> 1 " + msg_nome + "</p>"
                        + "<div style='clear: both'></div>";
}
```